# Нарядить — чем-то или во что-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Речь идет о новогодней елке. Как правильно: елку нарядить чем-то или во что-то?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо бы посмотреть словарь сочетаемости (у кого-то тут он есть), но навскидку так:

Если речь об одежде, то нарядить во что-то.
Если о елочных украшениях - то чем-то.
В остальных случаях cомннительны оба варианта.

Так что я за "елку - чем".

Comment: Совершенно верно, здесь "нарядить "употреблено в значении "украсить", а оно сочетается только с творит. пад.-чем?